# How the instance_eval work in ruby with dsl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i am learning to implement dsl in ruby but get confused with the uses of instance_eval.
my question is how the config variable get accessed in this code without calling the config method, and if the config method is called where it get called.

```
class Rails
  def self.configure (&block)
    instance_eval(&block)
  end 
  def self.config
   @config I|= {} 
  end
end
Rails.yes
Rails.configure do 
  config["feature"] = true
end
```

Comment: i have seen a lot of question with photos so i asked, and giving a screenshot of the code doesn't mean you are photographer and all. you can simply answer my question and in that you can mentioned to not use the ss.

Answer (score 0):

It is because when ruby see the config it either find the variable with config or method with config and here we haven't defined the variable with config but there's a method with name config so it called the config method.